# How to find the median (R,G,B) pixel value of all skin pixels in an image?

Tags: python, opencv

How to get the median pixel value (median RGB) of all skin pixels in the image here?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9tyS.jpg

I tried the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread('skin.png')
    COLOR1 = [0,0,0]
    COLOR2 = [10,10,10]
    image_copy = image.copy()
    black_pixels_mask = np.all(image <= COLOR2, axis=-1)
    non_black_pixels_mask = ~black_pixels_mask
    image_array = image_copy[non_black_pixels_mask]
    med = np.median(image_array, axis=0)
    print(med)
```

But this does not seem to give the correct answer. Please help!

Comment: When I execute your code I get three values `[142., 161., 200.]`, one median value for each RGB-channel. Isn't that what you want? If you like to have a single median value for all pixels regardless of the channel, just omit the `axis=0` in the median function.

Comment: what result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: @Tinu yes....that returns [142., 161., 200.]. But when I checked these RGB values to corresponding color, it shows some blueish color. I want to have the median value corresponds to skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I found: `(185.0, 155.0, 135.0)`

Here is the code. Pay attention that `split` returns the color sequence `b,g,r`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('skin.jpg')

def getMedianImageChannels(im):
    b, g, r = cv2.split(im) # Split channels
    # Remove zeros
    b = b[b != 0]
    g = g[g != 0]
    r = r[r != 0]
    # median values
    b_median = np.median(b)
    r_median = np.median(r)
    g_median = np.median(g)
    return r_median,g_median,b_median

median = getMedianImageChannels(image)
print(median)
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for. I hope it helps!